# Destructor in C# basic program does not work (output missing)

Tags: c#, constructor, garbage-collection, destructor

I have written the very basic program below, I am new to C#. The destructor ~Program() doesn't get called, so I do not see in the output the 'Destructor called' string. I have checked other similar questions but I don't find the answer to mine. Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using static System.Console;

namespace LyfeCicleObject
{
    class Program
    {
        public Program()
        {
            WriteLine("Cons called");
        }

        ~Program()
        {
            WriteLine("Destructor called");           
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WriteLine("Main started");

            Program p1 = new Program();
            {
                WriteLine("Block started");
                Program p2 = new Program();
                WriteLine("Block ended");
            }

            WriteLine("Main ended");
        }

        }

    }
```

Comment: There are no destructors in C#, thats a finalizer.

Comment: **[Finalizers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors)**

Comment: 99.9% of the time, you shouldn't be writing a finalizer. Can you talk us through why you think you need to write one?

Comment: By any chance are you running your code in .Net Core? That's what I was missing.

Comment: I have been coding in C# for nearly a quarter of a century and I have never hand written a finalizer.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer -- the reason you're not seeing the "Destructor called" output -- was buried somewhere in the comments:

> **.NET Core does not run finalizers at the end of the program**

(See: [Finalizers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors)).

.NET Framework will *attempt* to do it but .NET Core just won't do it.

***Disclaimer**: We have no way of knowing if these statements will continue to hold true; this is how they're implemented and documented as of now.*

According to Raymond Chen, though, in his post [Everybody thinks about garbage collection the wrong way](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203), it would not be invalid if .NET Framework didn't run finalizers at the end of the program, either.  The relevant quote, which says it from a different perspective, is this:

> A correctly-written program cannot assume that finalizers will ever run.

So as long as you don't assume that finalizers will run, it shouldn't matter how they're implemented or if an implementation changes.

Before going any further with C#, you're going to have to **abandon the idea of destructors in .NET** because they simply don't exist.  C# uses C++'s destructor *syntax* for finalizers but the similarities stop there.

The good news is that there *is* a way to do something close to what you were trying to do, but it takes a paradigm shift, a substantial change in how you think about resource acquisition and release.  Whether or not you really need to do it is a totally different question.

Finalizers aren't the only way, or even the best way, to release resources that need to be released in a timely manner.  We have the disposable pattern to help with that.

The disposable pattern allows class implementors to opt in to a common mechanism for deterministically releasing resources (not including memory on the managed heap).  It includes finalizers but only as a last chance at cleanup if the object wasn't disposed properly, especially if the process isn't terminating.

I'd say the main differences you'll see compared to C++ destructors are:

1. There's more that the class's implementor must do support the disposable pattern.
2. The class's consumer also has to opt in to it with a `using` statement.

What you won't see is that the memory won't necessarily be reclaimed immediately.

---

**If you want to know more about how, read on...**

Before I get into any code, it's worth mentioning some points of caution:

- A finalizer should never be empty. It causes instances to be kept alive longer and for nothing.
- As mjwills stated in a comment, 99.9% of the time, you shouldn't be writing a finalizer.  If you find yourself writing one, take a step back and make sure you have a good reason to do it in terms of .NET code and not because you would do it that way in C++.
- More often than not, you'll be overriding `Dispose(bool)` after deriving from a class that implements the disposable pattern rather than creating the base of a class hierarchy that needs to be disposable.  For example, the `.Designer.cs` files in Windows Forms applications override `Dispose(bool)` in order to dispose of the `components` field if it's not `null`.

Okay, code...

The following is an example of a simple class that implements the disposable pattern.  It doesn't provide support for child classes so it's marked `sealed` and `Dispose(bool)` is `private`.

```
public sealed class SimpleDisposable : IDisposable
{
    public SimpleDisposable()
    {
        // acquire resources
    }

    ~SimpleDisposable()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Suppress calling the finalizer because resources will have been released by then.
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        Dispose(true);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // release managed resources
            // (you don't want to do this when calling from the finalizer because the GC may have already finalized and collected them)
        }

        // release unmanaged resources
    }
}
```

Actual cleanup takes place in the `Dispose(bool)` method.  If the parameter is `true`, it means that disposal is happening via the `IDisposable` interface (usually a `using` statement but not necessarily) and it's okay to clean up *managed* resources as well.  If it's `false`, it means that disposal is happening as part of a GC sweep, so you can't touch managed resources because they may have already been collected.

If you're writing a base class that needs to support the disposable pattern, things change slightly: `Dispose(bool)` is becomes `protected` and `virtual` so it can be overridden by subclasses but is still inaccessible to the consumer.

The following is an example of a base class that supports the disposable pattern for subclasses.

```
public abstract class BaseDisposable : IDisposable
{
    protected BaseDisposable()
    {
        // acquire resources
    }

    ~BaseDisposable()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        Dispose(true);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // release managed resources
        }

        // release unmanaged resoures
    }
}
```

And then the following is a subclass that uses that support.  Subclasses don't also need to implement the finalizer or `IDisposable.Dispose`.  All they have to do is override `Dispose(bool)`, dispose of their own resources, and then call the base implementation.

```
public class DerivedDisposable : BaseDisposable
{
    public DerivedDisposable()
    {
        // acquire resources for DerivedDisposable
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // release DerivedDisposable's managed resources
        }

        // release DerivedDisposable's unmanaged resources

        // Let the base class do its thing
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

So what does it mean to dispose managed and unmanaged resources?

Managed resources are things like other disposable objects and even non-disposable objects (e.g. strings).  Some disposable types in the BCL will set such fields to `null` to ensure that the GC doesn't find active references to them.

When your class is being disposed, the consumer has decided that it and its resources are no longer needed.  If your object contains other disposables, it's okay to dispose those objects, and so on down the chain, because it's not happening during garbage collection.

Unmanaged resources are things like file handles, global memory, kernel objects... pretty much anything you allocated by making a call to the operating system.  Those aren't affected by the garbage collector and need to be released no matter what, so they're not subject to the `disposing` test.

If your disposable object used another disposable object that has an unmanaged resource, it's that object's responsibility to implement the Disposable pattern to release its resources, and your responsibility to use it.

Not all objects that implement `IDisposable` actually have unmanaged resources.  Often a base class will support the disposable pattern simply because its author knows that at least one class that derives from it might need to use unmanaged resources.  However, if a class doesn't implement the disposable pattern, one of its subclasses can introduce that support if it needs it.

---

Let's alter your program a bit and make it do what you were expecting, but using the disposable pattern now.

*Note: As far as I know, it's not very common to have `Main` create an instance of the containing `Program` class.  I'm doing it here to keep things as close to the original as possible.*

```
using System;

internal sealed class Program : IDisposable
{
    private readonly string _instanceName;

    public Program(string instanceName)
    {
        _instanceName = instanceName;

        Console.WriteLine($"Initializing the '{_instanceName}' instance");
    }

    ~Program()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        Dispose(true);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Releasing the '{_instanceName}' instance's managed resources");
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Releasing the '{_instanceName}' instance's unmanaged resources");
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main started");

        Program p0 = new Program(nameof(p0));
        using (Program p1 = new Program(nameof(p1)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Outer using block started");
            using (Program p2 = new Program(nameof(p2)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Inner using block started");
                Console.WriteLine("Inner using block ended");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Outer using block ended");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Main ended");
    }
}
```

Build and run against .NET Framework 4.7.2 and you get the following output:

```
Main started
Initializing the 'p0' instance
Initializing the 'p1' instance
Outer using block started
Initializing the 'p2' instance
Inner using block started
Inner using block ended
Releasing the 'p2' instance's managed resources
Releasing the 'p2' instance's unmanaged resources
Outer using block ended
Releasing the 'p1' instance's managed resources
Releasing the 'p1' instance's unmanaged resources
Main ended
Releasing the 'p0' instance's unmanaged resources
```

Build and run against .NET Core 2.1 and you get the following output:

```
Main started
Initializing the 'p0' instance
Initializing the 'p1' instance
Outer using block started
Initializing the 'p2' instance
Inner using block started
Inner using block ended
Releasing the 'p2' instance's managed resources
Releasing the 'p2' instance's unmanaged resources
Outer using block ended
Releasing the 'p1' instance's managed resources
Releasing the 'p1' instance's unmanaged resources
Main ended
```

Instances `p1` and `p2` were disposed in the reverse order in which they were constructed because of the `using` statements, and both managed and unmanaged resources were released.  This was the desired behavior behind trying to use a "destructor".

On the other hand, .NET Framework and .NET Core did things a bit different at the end, showing the differences I mentioned at the beginning:

- .NET Framework's GC called the finalizer for `p0` so it only released the unmanaged resources.
- .NET Core's GC did not call the finalizer for `p0`.

Comment: Thanks @madreflection. I'll have a deeper look into it once I go back to coding :)

Comment: This was quite informative. specially the part of difference between how .net framework till 4.7 used to call the Finalizer but not .Net Core. I had recently started building my program in .Net core and was wondering why my code inside the finalizer was not executing. Thanks!

Comment: new updated link to raymond chens blog is [Everybody thinks about garbage collection the wrong way](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203)

Comment: Funny, I've used that link in comments several times. I didn't realize I still had the old one here. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the output from finalizer:

- add new method
- initialize variable p1 inside
- add GC.Collect()
- call new method from Main
- profit

If you want to know the reason of current behavior: the `p1` variable exists in the scope of the `Main` method and will be collected by the GC when scope gets unreachable and I suppose it happens when program already stopped that means no GC (memory will be released in another way).

Comment: The finalizers will be called when the program ends. The reason why the asker doesn't see its output is probably due to the console window immediately closing afterwards (assuming the program is run in the debugger from VS)

Comment: @elgonzo According to [Everybody thinks about garbage collection the wrong way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/09/10047586.aspx), the GC doesn't even have to collect memory and call finalizers when the program ends.

Comment: @madreflection, the CLR tries to cleanup the finalizer queue when the program is ending. There are a number of factors that can cause this to not happen or be aborted halfway through, but in this simple program given here the finalizers _should_ be executed when the program ends...

Comment: @elgonzo do you have any information about relation between finalization and program size?

Comment: Yes and no.  I just ran the exact same code from the console, built for .NET Framework 4.7 and .NET Core 2.1. .NET Framework 4.7 ran the finalizer (twice, actually). .NET Core 2.1 did not.

Comment: @ArturScherbakov, No. Why do you think program size and finalization relate? How do you define program size? What relation do you see?

Comment: ...and WelcomeOverflow's link states as much.

Comment: @madreflection, yes, you will see the output of the finalizer twice, because the code in the question creates 2 `Program` instances ;-)

Comment: D'oh. I see that now.

Comment: @elgonzo so, maybe i've misunderstood this part ` but in this simple program given here the finalizers should be executed` from your answer.

Comment: @madreflection, interesting that .NET Core did not seem to attempt cleaning up the finalizer queue. I am curious whether this fact is documented somewhere (i leave googling this for some other time...)

Comment: As I mentioned, the link that WelcomeOverflow provided above does say that .NET Core doesn't (documentation enough? you decide). I believe it's because that memory can simply be reclaimed by the OS. For the most part, any handles (file, socket, etc.) are also reclaimed by the OS when the process terminates.

Comment: @ArturScherbakov, in this simple program here, there should be no adverse factors preventing the CLR from successfully and rather speedily cleaning up the finalizer queue at the program end. The finalizers in the code given will not hang nor throw, nor do they do anything complex or complicated. They just simply(!) do a single line of console output. Nothing that should stall or abort the finalization attempt. (Note madreflections comment, though. It seems, the behavior between .NET framework and .NET core differs in this respect)

Comment: @madreflection, my bad and my apologies. I didn't notice that the documentation mentioned this fact (and i misinterpreted your comment referring to the link provided by WelcomeOverflow, not connecting it with your prior comment; again, my apologies)

Comment: @elgonzo No apology necessary.

Comment: @Artur Scherbakov, thanks for the answer. I have tried with your suggestion but it's still not working. I am working with .NET Core and using the most recent version of VS Community. Is there anything I should activate on VS so it would work? Sorry for the lame question but I am really a newbie. Thanks