# On which thread does the Finalizer get called on UWP/C#

Tags: c#, uwp, garbage-collection, finalizer

I have a instance of MediaPlayer inside a singleton class. Class is in being injected to consumers via autofact as singleton instance.

```cs
public class SMTCControl 
{
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    ~SMTCControl ()
    {
        coreDispatcher.TryRunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, ()=>
        {
            mediaPlayer.Dispose();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        });
    }

    public SMTCControl ()
    {
        coreDispatcher.TryRunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, ()=>
        {
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        });            
    }

    public IMediaPlaybackSource Source
    {
        get => mediaPlayer.Source;
        set => mediaPlayer.Source = value;
    }

    public MediaPlaybackCommandManager CommandManager => mediaPlayer.CommandManager;

    public SystemMediaTransportControls SystemMediaTransportControls => 
        mediaPlayer.SystemMediaTransportControls;
}
```

SMTC has bug where it leaks the memory if i create and dispose this other than UI thread.

So I used `coreDispatcher.TryRunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, handler);` to init and dispose the mediaplayer.

If I use the `coreDispatcher.TryRunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, handler);` in finalizer to dispose the object then it causes a new task to queued-up in UI thread but class's finalizer is already exit the call because TryRunAsync will run into different thread.

My question are:

1. On which thread actually finalizer gets called. I heared it's UI message Loop, is that same as UI thread? Breakpoints are not greeting hit on finalizer code.
2. Since the singleton will get dispose when user quits the app, so is it really required to dispose the object? If there is no app running it means no memory to clean up.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54316893/destructor-in-c-sharp-basic-program-does-not-work-output-missing

Comment: One takeaway is that you can't always rely on the garbage collector running at the end of the program.  .NET 5, the sucessor to .NET Core, probably will continue not to do so, unlike the .NET Framework.  As Windows-specific UI technologies become supported on .NET Core, this will likely become relevant to UWP, too.