# C# and what not to do in a finalizer

Tags: c#, idisposable, finalizer

I read something about what not to do within a C# Finalizer and for the life of me I can't find the link.

When the destructor is called, is it safe to use reference objects within that class which owns the destructor?

I believe this is what I was reading about. But if that's the case, the destructor could not call a Dispose method to clean up un-managed resources, correct?

Note: I'm aware of IDisposable and the common implementation.

Comment: The rule of thumb: don't do anything in finalizers. There are possible usages (such as safety nets if you forgot to return a resource), but they also are questionable.

Comment: Then why have the finalizer at all? *IF* it's not safe to use any reference member object in the finalizer, that means you can't even call the Dispose method of reference properties and rely upon the user of your class to call Dispose or use the Using statement.

Comment: You dispose of non-managed resources, like Win32 handles, in finalizers. IIRC it's not safe to use managed objects, because they might already have been disposed.

Comment: @R.J.Dunnill What if I have a member reference object (like StreamWriter) and want to make sure it's disposed of? I couldn't really do so from the Finalizer right?

Comment: The finalizer is basically a last-chance opportunity to call `Dispose(false)`. And because you pass `false`, `Dispose(bool)` should have `if (disposing) {...}` around that wouldn't run in that case. That block only runs if you need to release managed resources when `Dispose()` -> `Dispose(true)` is called at the end of a `using` block.

Comment: No, and the garbage collector will take care of it, because it's a managed object.

Comment: @R.J.Dunnill the garbage collector will take care of it, eventually. That doesn't help me if I want to use the same resource (file, whatever) from some other object immediately after an instance of my object goes out of scope. Do we just blame the user (of "my" class) and say they should have used the Using statement or called my classes Dispose(true)?

Comment: The key here is you can't *assume* anything to exist. So any reference object you try to use may be null. You have to check that the object exists first, and you can only call other methods which can live under those assumptions. You should only be ensuring you've freed unmanaged resources.

Comment: You can read about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors. As @R.J.Dunnill said, it can be used for freeing unmanaged resources. I'm ashamed to say that I don't understand why it can't be done in `Dispose` (you were able to allocate a resource, shy aren't you able to free it?). The big problem with finalizers is that it can be called arbitrarily late.

Comment: If the issue is an unmanaged resource, bear in mind that `IDisposable` is your friend, and the finalizer may not be called for seconds after the object goes out of scope - it's only on particular GC passes (which, depending on your garbage generation, may be more or less frequent) which collect finalizer objects.

Comment: @Zarenor Checking the object exists would be a race condition wouldn't it? The garbage collector runs on its own thread right?

Comment: Right, you can't check that it exists. If you're in a GC cycle, assume that any managed references you have could be invalid and just don't touch them.

Comment: @dyukha It can be called in Dispose. The issue is when Dispose is called by the Finalizer (false is passed). At this point reference members of the class may no longer be valid object (I believe I have that correct).

Comment: And *yes*. The consumer of your class has to play fair. We repeatedly have to tell new programmers to put `using` blocks on connections, files, etc. here on SO.

Comment: @madreflection What happens when I want to have, for example, a StreamWriter left open in my class for the life of my class, but expect the same file it points to, to be usable when my class object goes out of scope? I guess in this case the user of my class is expected to call Dispose or use Using, and if he doesn't the bug is his and not mind.

Comment: That's the long and short of it. And that last point is key: it's not your bug because you've done what it takes to dispose it at the best possible point in time for *your* code. It's the consumer's bug for not telling you that you can dispose of it quickly rather than falling back on a GC cycle.

Comment: If I'm doing using the MVC pattern, and if I have IDisposable objects injected into my Controller, how would I call dispose of the injected object? Or, I suppose the solution is that the injected object should not leave resources open for the life of the object?

Comment: Also, can my Dispose(bool disposing) function call base.Dispose() even if disposing is false? Or should I only call base.Dispose if disposing is true? I'm using the standard disposable implementation. I want to call base.Dispose so I have some idea of when resources will be cleaned up. Or do I treat it like any other reference variable (ie: don't use it unless disposing == true).

Comment: The container should be disposing them for you for transient registrations. I don't know all the details, but ASP.NET opens a new scope to handle the request. Since the same instance is returned within the scope for each transient registration wherever it's needed, the container is tracking the instances it gives you and disposes them for you when the scope is closed at the end of the request. Each container is different so you'll have to read up on the one you're using.

Comment: Your `Dispose(bool)` *should* call `base.Dispose(disposing)` so that the base implementation can clean up whatever it needs to, *with* the same knowledge of whether it's being called from `IDisposable.Dispose()` or the finalizer so it can behave accordingly. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54361746/5394572); there's an example of how to do that.

Comment: @madreflection Function Dispose() in the parent class will almost certainly be private though right?

Comment: No, the pattern requires that it's `protected` so it can be called by overriding methods in derived classes. You should take a look at disposables using ILSpy. It'll be very informative. `System.IO.FileStream` is a good example. The only time it would be `private` is when the type introduces `IDisposable` and is sealed (e.g. structs).

Comment: @DeveloperWebs - (misunderstood previous comment) - The `Dispose()` that implements `IDisposable.Dispose` cannot be *marked* private, but it can be private by way of explicitly implementing that method, or marked public by implicitly implementing it. That has nothing to do with the disposable pattern, though; it's just how you implement an interface.

Comment: @madreflection Sorry, I meant Dispose(bool X) will be private in the parent. You said to call base.Dispose(disposing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic gist of the "rules" is from within a finizer you can only call objects that have a known live root (for example all static objects) and objects that don't have a live root that also derive from `CriticalFinalizerObject`, unless you are a `CriticalFinalizerObject` then you are not allowed to call other `CriticalFinalizerObject`s.

Most objects in your own class the finalizer is in will likely be off limits to touch because they are not on a live root (your class is being finalized after all) and they don't inherit from `CriticalFinalizerObject`.

There is a very good article "[What Your Mother Never Told You About Resource Deallocation](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29534/IDisposable-What-Your-Mother-Never-Told-You-About)" that explains what can and can't be done during a finalizer and explains a pattern by using `SafeHandle` for all unmanaged resources gets rid of the need of you ever needing to write a finalizer yourself. The article is a very long read but try to read it all and understand it, it really opened my mind to everything I was doing right, and wrong, about disposing managed and unmanaged objects.

The article goes through and describes how to use `SafeHandle`, (a class derived from `CriticalFinalizerObject` and is IDisposable) so that you never need to worry about writing your own finializer.

Comment: Though, in this case, the issue is disposing of managed resources which own un-managed resources. I don't have an OS-level system handle.

Comment: The article goes in to that. SafeHandle is not for only resources that have a handle. The section of the article for your specific use case is called ***"Wrapping Unmanaged Resources - Defining Level 0 Types for Non-Pointer Data (The Hard Case)"***

Comment: Refresh this answer, I copied the wrong section title and fixed it, in that section you are describing the second implementation, the one that does not use casting and IntPtr.

Comment: I guess I don't understand, I understand that section to be talking about pointers or things that can be represented with a ushort. In my case I have an instance of a StreamWriter object (the entire object), and its own Dispose method is responsible for dealing with whatever resources it opens in that black box, in fact its own Dispose must be the only thing to cleanup its own resources.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the problem. However, I can answer your last two questions in the comments, In the case of MVC usually the IoC container you are using will handle the disposing of objects when the lifetime for the object is ended. For the `Dispose(bool disposing)` question, no you should not call `base.Dispose()` as it may try to use managed resources that could already be finalized. However, if you have a `base.Dispose(disposing)` you could call then that would be fine because you can pass in the false to tell the base that it is not allowed to use managed objects.

Comment: However, microsoft itself does not recommend you use a `Dispose(bool disposing)` at all. If you read the documentation on implementing a disposable object you will find a section called [Using Safe Handles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose?view=netframework-4.8#using-safe-handles), it says (emphasis mine) "Writing code for an object's finalizer is a complex task that can cause problems if not done correctly. *Therefore, we recommend that you construct System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle objects instead of implementing a finalizer.*"

Comment: How would I use a SafeHandle to cause Dispose() be called upon the StreamWriter instance which is a member of my IDisposable class?

Comment: If you don't call base.Dispose(), how does the parent Disposable class get cleaned up when my class (which derives from some IDisposable parent) goes out of scope? If I don't call base.Dispose(), any underlying resources won't be cleaned up for an indeterminate amount of time. If my class has a StreamWriter member, and I want to call Dispose on that StreamWriter instance when my class goes out of scope, how does SafeHandle help do that?